# proof of "conjugacy theorem of BSA" following Humphreys

Tags: proof-verification, representation-theory, lie-algebras, proof-explanation

Please follow the book [here](http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/~alberto/apuntes/humphreys.pdf)

Section: $16.4$  Proof of the theorem:
(1) When $B\cap B'\neq 0$
case (ii) $B\cap B'$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements. Let $T=B\cap B'$. Then the author shows that we may assume $T\subset H$.

My question: $B\cap B'\subset B$ and has no nonzero nilpotent elements in it and $B$ is standard with respect to CSA, $H$. And we know that a BSA contains $x_s$ and $x_n$, the semisimple and the nilpotent part of the elements $x$ in it. So $T\cap N=0$. Hence $T\subset H$.

Is there anything I've missed? I'm not getting why did he prove that "we may assume" ?

Comment: $B\cap B'$ is not a BSA, so even though $B$ contains both $x_s$ and $x_n$, it does not follow that the intersection does.

Comment: @DavidHill: I got the proof! but can you help me, to understand what is the motivation behind constructing $S$ , (case $B\cap B'$ has no nonzero nilpotent element , $B\cap B'\subsetneq H$, $B'\not\subset C_LT$)